# How to use SUM and VLOOKUP formula together in multiple cells?

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup

Say I have an excel file which looks like below:

[image]

How do I get values of all the columns in below table fields **Quarter-1,  Quarter-2,  Quarter-3,  Quarter-4** in one go, where Quarter-1 is the sum of the values from Jan--2018 to Mar--2018 in the above table, Quarter-2 is the sum of the values from Apr--2018 to Jun--2018 etc.

Now, I've written the below formula's in **Quarter-1,  Quarter-2,  Quarter-3,  Quarter-4** respectively

```
{=SUM(VLOOKUP([@Name],Table1[[#All],[Name]:[Dec--2018]],{2,3,4},0))}

{=SUM(VLOOKUP([@Name],Table1[[#All],[Name]:[Dec--2018]],{5,6,7},0))}

{=SUM(VLOOKUP([@Name],Table1[[#All],[Name]:[Dec--2018]],{8,9,10},0))}

{=SUM(VLOOKUP([@Name],Table1[[#All],[Name]:[Dec--2018]],{11,12,13},0))}
```

But can I do this using a single formula and not need to change the column index array values in every column?

[SAMPLE FILE](https://ufile.io/4y7vo)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez How do I do that? Can you show?

Comment: Check [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I know SUMIFS function but can't figure out how to use it with VLOOKUP in this case??